# Test Google API with HTML PUT request

Tags: html, google-api, put

I'm trying to test a simple form to reset users password in gmail

```
<form action="https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users"” method=”put” if-match="*">
  <input name="userKey" type="text" value="" />
  <input name="password" type="text" value="" />
  <input name="key" type="text" value="" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

I have this error

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "required",
    "message": "Login Required",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "Authorization"
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Login Required"
 }
}
```

How can I do a put request in html?

Comment: you probably cant because you will need to be authenticated first this is going to require some kind of programing language not html.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of reasons why you can't quite do what you're trying to do. Although https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/update talks about updating an account using the Directory API, and this API uses URLs and HTTPS connections, this is mostly meant for back-end systems to use a fairly standard REST-based API instead of people to use a web browser directly.

You may be able to get away with a JavaScript-based AJAX call to do this, but even that is probably not a good idea.

For starters, the user will need to be authenticated, and they need to be authorized to use the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user` scope. Since tokens with this scope have a **lot** of power (including the power to change **other** user accounts), this probably wouldn't be a power you want to give a person. If it was - they would be able to change **any** of the fields of themselves (or possibly anyone).

Secondly, as part of the reply done using this form or AJAX, you'll need to include this auth token, and it really isn't something you can just stick in the form.

Relatedly, the body of the request needs to be in JSON format. While there are proposals out there to allow browsers to do this, as far as I know, no browser currently supports a form encoding type of "application/json".

Your best bet is to create a simple application server, protected using Google's Sign-In to authenticate the user, which provides the form and checks it to make sure this is a reasonable request. You can verify the user at that time and let them change the password, but not provide them access to anything else. You would use a service account, which would have the `admin.directory.user` role, to do the actual change based on the sanitized inputs from the user.

Comment: My goal is to create a self service portal, if a AJAX call is not a good idea who could I do it?

Comment: As noted in the last paragraph - creating an application server (the portal) that authenticates the user and then does the work on their behalf using a service account.